# Angular 6: Is it possible to pass a function as parameter?

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a modal-form template that I would like to create with some shared functionalities. Mainly two buttons at the bottom: one to cancel and one to run any function (essentially it could `save()`, `next()`, etc.).

I know you can interpolate and bind data, but functions?

Is it possible to pass a function, specifically for a click handler?

MODAL TEMPLATE:

```
//modal-template.html

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="{{someFunction()}}">Save</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Cancel</button>
    </div>


//modal-template.ts

import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModal, NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal-template',
  templateUrl: './modal-template.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal-template.component.css']
})
export class ModalTemplateComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

MODAL-COMPONENT:

```
//custom-modal.component.html

<app-modal-template (click)="someFunction()">
  <app-custom-modal></app-custom-modal>
</app-modal-template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible ! you just need **@Output click = new EventEmitter();** in your modal template, you can read about [documentation here](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)

```
//modal-template.html    
<div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="someFunction()">Save</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Cancel</button>
    </div>


@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal-template',
  templateUrl: './modal-template.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal-template.component.css']
})
export class ModalTemplateComponent implements OnInit {
   @Output() click = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

 someFunction() { 
       this.click.emit(); //this line, execute the function you pass it !
 }



}
```

if you still not understand how that's work, maybe this [blog with help you.](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-output-and-eventemitter-in-angular)

Comment: Hey Muhammad! Thanks to your links, I was able to understand Outputs more and get them to work from child > parent :)

From what I learned, I've been trying to go one level deeper when passing a function but no luck. I'm trying to pass through three levels, if that makes sense. child > parent > super parent?. I have a component > template > parent. Please help!

Here is a Stackblitz that mimics my code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jdfkld

Thanks many :)